# toggle sibling element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I m trying to toggle a sibling class.

```
<tr id='user-1' class="alternate">
<td><button type="button" class='more_info'>Open</button></td>
</tr>

<tr id='user-1' style='display:none;' class='more_info_2'>
<td>Something</td>
</tr>
```

I want to fade in the .more_info_2 class when .more_info is clicked.

I've tried everything... siblings(), next(), children()...

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".more_info").click(function(){
$(this).siblings(".more_info").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

However nothing works for me...
Maybe my html structure is wrong or something...Please help.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: None of your elements has the class `aaa`. And the button with class `more_info` doesn't have any siblings, it's the only element in the cell. So what do you want to toggle exactly? Also, post the **generated** HTML, not your PHP code.

Comment: Also, IDs **must** be unique. Your rows share the same.

Comment: Just a heads up, I believe it is now recommended that you use the `on()` method so it would be `$(".more_info").on("click", function(){yada yada yada})`

Comment: If you got your answer please approve it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the second `<tr>` you need something more lie this:

```
$(".more_info").click(function () {
    $(this).parents("tr").next().toggle();
});
```

You can see the Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/89SRg/

Comment: No problem. As a friendly tip, to make it easier to help you in the future, please remove your PHP code and replace it with what you expect to be there. Good luck! :)

Comment: @user3693102 - please mark your question answered, if you wouldn't mind :) Thanks and have a great Monday!

Answer (score 0):

**First:** fix the IDs. You can't have two elements on the same page with the same ID.

**Second:** change this:

```
$(this).siblings(".more_info").toggle();
```

To this:

```
$(this).closest("TR").next().toggle();
```

Your `.more_info` button has no siblings. What you really want is its parent row's next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just assigning to a given class you don't even need to use `.parents` or `.next`. Plus you said you want it to fade in so just use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".more_info").click(function () {
        $(".more_info_2").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Making sure your table elements are wrapped in a `<table>...</table>` tag of course.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/PLmnf/2/)